# Python execute a file, then delete it

Tags: python

Hi Stackoverflow experts, this is a hard one, for Python programmers.

I'm working on an encrypted SQLITE3 container, written in Python. The final target are users, not developers.

All the functions are working as expected, but my problem is with a function to EXECUTE files from the container.

How the EXECUTE works:

1. i create a temporary folder with tempfile.mkdtemp
2. i decrypt the file from the container, into that folder (from what i know, this is the only way to open a file)
3. A: on Windows, i execute the file with os.system('file_name & exit'), so the file is opened with the default app (ex: images with fax viewer by default, music with media player by default, etc, etc). This is usually blocking.
4. B: on Ubuntu/ Mint (it's all i tested so far), i execute with subprocess.check_output(['xdg-open', file_name]), but this is not always blocking (ex: when you open one text file by default with Gedit, if Gedit is already open, the function returns immediately).
5. i delete the file
6. i delete the temporary folder, because it's not automatically deleted

Ok, so steps 1 and 2 are ok. I would prefer NOT to write the file on HDD, for example i want to execute it from memory, but you need to tell each app WHERE to open a file from, it must be a path from HDD, right?

The most secure would be to implement my own internal viewers for text, images, music, video, so i don't need to export the data on HDD. But this is not realistic :)

So the problem are steps 4 and 5. How do i know WHEN to delete the file after execution, if the execution is not blocking ?...

I tried all the functions from subprocess (wait, communicate, check_call) and os.system, to make the execution blocking... Maybe there are other functions to wait for processes to finish ?...

Maybe there is a way to delete the temporary files automatically ? Or i should make a list on runtime and delete them when the program closes...

Maybe there is a way to check if a file is opened by some app ? Ex: "my-pic.jpg" is opened by Image-Viewer, so i cannot delete it yet, but i will check again in a few seconds and if no other app uses it, i can delete it. // Maybe with "ps ax | grep my-pic" i can find if the file is open. But this doesn't work on Windows.

Any ideas, any sugestions ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: If the process is non-blocking, I don't think there's any way to know when it closes the file. Also, remember that any editor may autosave copies of the file elsewhere without telling you. And even when you delete it, the data remains on the hard drive until it gets overwritten. What sort of attack are you trying to protect against?

Comment: @ThomasK Thank you for your comment. I know that Gedit saves backup copies on edit, and most image viewers save thumbnails and also cache images, etc. So, if you open a file externally, there is always a great risk of exposing your private data, stored in the container. That's why i said before that i prefer to open them internally. Anyway, i'm trying to protect against accessing the data from the container. The metadata for each file is not encrypted, so anyone can tell what kind of data it is, but cannot decrypt it unless it knows the password.

Comment: Who are you trying to prevent from accessing that data? Another user with access to the database? another user logged into the same computer at the same time? another user who logs in afterwards? another user who later has full physical access to the drive? the same user after they're supposed to have finished with it? potential malicious software that may be running on the computer? Do you control the computer it's opening the file on, or does the user?

Comment: @ThomasK : Only a few persons can know the password that decrypts the files from container; typically, a person puts some files and only that person uses the container, over and over and over again. It's not one-time use. You can upload a container on DropBox or keep it at work as private container, etc. I hope this answers the question, but i don't understand how this matters.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

- make the user tell your application when he has no longer need of the temporarily extracted files
- query the Windows API to find out [which processes are using files in a certain folder](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/OpenedFileFinder.aspx?fid=422864&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=26&select=2277170) (e.g. your temp folder)
- in any case, *try* to delete the file shortly after opening it; this might often work, because many applications do not protect the files that they're using, i.e. they allow other applications to modify/delete a file even while they're using it
- have a look at [PendMoves/MoveFile](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897556). Maybe you can implement something similar for your application.
- create a small RamDisk for your application and use it to store the temporary files in
- use TrueCrypt or similar tools for mounting encrypted containers (managed by your application) to store the temporary files in and - if necessary - force un-mounting of these containers.

Comment: Thank you for your great ideas! I will study them all. The last are the most secure, but they might require admin privileges. I don't know any RamDisk portable apps except for TrueCrypt. Thank you again !